# Xcode 8.0 get crashed when conforming to `CustomStringConvertible` protocol in playground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-playground

I get Xcode crash error `The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-roc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.`  when conforming to `CustomStringConvertible` protocol in playground?!

*this happens for Xcode version 8.0

Comment: Please keep in mind that Xcode 8 and the version of Swift it supports are terribly out-of-date. You'll thank yourself later if you upgrade to Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5.

Comment: Ah Okay thanks! @rmaddy